# Permutation and Combination Question

Tags: combinatorics

How many $3$ digits numbers are there, whose written form contains exactly two consecutive digits $3$?

Comment: surely you can just write them down?

Comment: @Vyas, I'm glad to see you engaged more in the comments, +1 - if you ask another question it would be better to put more context and (if appropriate) any thoughts alongside the question.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

There are two kinds of these numbers, written as $\;\color{red}{33x}$, where $\;x\in \{\dots\}$, or $\;\color{red}{x33}$, where  $\;x\in \{\dots\}$.

Comment: The Question is hard to understand for a 5th grader. How can this be made simpler?

Comment: What's hard in enumerating  the possibilities for $x$? One more hint: the sets of possibilities are not exactly the same in both cases.

Comment: got it.. 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 133, 233, 433, 533, 633, 733, 833, 933

Comment: do we include 330?

Comment: Yes, we include $330$.  Careful:  $333$ has three consecutive threes, and you need to count only those with *exactly two consecutive $3$'*.

Comment: You have one intruder.

Comment: ok, I see.. Thank you 330, 331, 332, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 133, 233, 433, 533, 633, 733, 833, 933

Comment: Are you a digit ;o) ?